# parse currency formated number to float in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column in mysql of float type, I need to load currency like numbers($300) into this column, how do I do that in MYSQL?  (let's not argue about the choice of float for this column)

Comment: Are you having trouble doing this? Can you give us an error message or something to work off of?

Comment: Are you loading from a file or another table?  "$300" with the dollar sign?

Comment: I am using load FILE command from MYSQL to load the cvs into database, basically $300 with dollar sign doesn't get loaded as 300 into the float cell. it simly becomes NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create temporary table with `varchar2` instead of `float`
- load file in temporary table
- copy data from temporary table to real table and use msql [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html) to convert the currency into a float, using something like:

  `(CAST ( SUBSTRING( TRIM( amountStr ), 1 ) AS FLOAT )`

Comment: FLOAT is not a supported by the CAST function. Each part of a decimal number would need to be parsed out as a separate int value and added back together. The int after the decimal point would need to be divided by 100.